# Magento - How to Add a custom tab Under Product Information in the Admin panel?

Tags: magento

I have been working on a new customization for my magento website. Now i am trying to add a custom tab "Price - Size" with the default tab list. How do i do it? any reference would be helpful..!

Below is the screenshot of what i am expecting to have (I will place some size-pricing information in the main area when user clicks this tab)

Thanks

[image]

Comment: HI Balanv How to create admin panel left bar in product tags? I tried using this following url But i can`t achieve it ...Please guide me how to create admin panel left bar in admin product..?

Comment: Try this link from Oguz, http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin/ i could able to implement this by following the steps in this url.

Comment: Try this URL:  http://www.jyotiranjan.in/blog/add-custom-tab-in-product-edit-section-of-admin/  implement this by following the steps in this url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do by attributes, like the following.

1. Go to Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes Set
2. Add new attribute set based "Default"
3. Go to Manage Attributes
4. Add new Attributes
5. Give unique attribute code and fill other necessary fields.
6. Click "Manage Label / Options", fill labels what you want.
7. Go to Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes set, then click the new created set.
8. Add new "Group", give a proper name.
9. Select attribute that you want to attach this created new group from right panel ( drag and drop on the new group )
10. Create new product, select the attribute that you created a few seconds ago.

The finally, you will new attribute in the product page left sidebar.

Comment: Thanks Oguz.. i could able to add a new tab right away with this..
But i am trying to have a fully customized tab.. which i would like to add it using code, i would then create a page with variety of fields i require in the main area, when user clicks this newly created tab..

Comment: @balanv then use this link http://fishpig.co.uk/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin/